# Installing ADFS throws a "null parameter"

Tags: powershell, installation, adfs

This is a portion of my script for installing ADFS. Pretty straightforward, but it seems Start-Process is parsing switches in a funny way. Is there something I'm missing?

```
write-host "Installing ADFS - process should take 30-45 seconds"
$installtime=get-date -uformat "%Y_%h_%d_%H_%M"
$logfile="$pwd\adfssetup_$installtime.log"
$ADFSInstall = "AdfsSetup.exe"
$ADFSInstallParams = '/quiet /logfile '+$logfile
Start-Process $ADFSInstall $ADFSInstallParams -wait
if ({gc -path $logfile | select-string -pattern "AD FS 2.0 is already installed on this computer"} -eq $null){write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "ADFS Installed"} Else{write-host -ForegroundColor "There was an error Installing ADFS, please check the log file: $logfile;break}
```

If I Execute the above script I get the following in a log file:

```
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Setup Error: 5124 :   6 [ 2070099085 ]: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Setup.Diagnostics.TraceLog.WriteLine(TraceEventType eventType, String msg, Object[] args)
```

If I execute the exact same command manually (from the output of write-host), everything works fine.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: No answer here. Lets guess ... in $pwd there is a white space in the path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant delete the question, but what I found by investigating older logs is that the error occurs even when I run the command the regular way. So the above script is actually working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't really understand what is happening here, but here are two possibilities.)

One option is that your `get-date` does not work as you intend.  The result is that `$logfile` contains a percent sign (`%`), which causes 'format string injection' in the AD FS 2.0 installer.  The error message points in that direction.

However, I cannot reproduce that if I run your PowerShell script on my own system.

Also note that it looks like you're passing three command line arguments (`/quiet`, `/logfile`, and the log file name) in one argument.  Try passing them like so:

```
$ADFSInstallParams = @('/quiet', '/logfile', $logfile)
Start-Process $ADFSInstall @ADFSInstallParams -wait
```

However, if this were the cause of the problem then I would have expected `adfssetup.exe` to complain with an error like `command line argument '/quiet /logfile ...' not recognized`.

Comment: You're right. And what I found by investigating older logs (actually ran undelete program to get them), is that the error occurs even when I run ADFSSetup.exe the regular way. So the above script is actually working as intended.

Thanks for your help.